# RHEL 8: Administrator vs. Auditor role

Tags: redhat, audit, security-groups, rhel8, administrative-privileges

On RHEL 8, are there prepared functions, methods, processes or tools to implement administrator/operator and  auditor roles in the following way:

- An administrator/operator should be able to do almost everything except modifying/deleting logs
- An auditor should be able to read everything, and to delete logs

On my research, I did not find any hints or best practices for this concept. But I imagine, that this might be a common requirement for systems that shall comply with ISO 27001. So I am whondering, if there are already *maintainable* solutions to implpement such roles on RHEL or if it can be accomplished at all or if this is (*currently*) just not feasible on RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are some ready made provisions for privilege separation in SELinux in Multi Level  Security mode [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/using-multi-level-security-mls_using-selinux#proc_separating-system-administration-from-security-administration-in-mls_using-multi-level-security-mls) but nothing immediately useful and practical.

When you need to protect and tamperproof log files and audit trails against the trusted administrators on a server the solution is almost always either:

- copy those log files and audit trails to a remote location where those administrators do not have access at all or only limited access and where they are not trusted users.
  In other words: the auditor sets up and maintains a central syslog server and/or for example a Splunk/ELK Stack or similar where the other administrators don't get access to (or will only have user level access) and therefore won't be able to delete/modify the records. All (critical) application logs get copied there.
- write those logs to [WORM media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) - although that may have been much more popular in the past than it is today

Comment: Off-loading the log files is indeed a good workaround before implementing sth. complex/hard to maintain.